# Does "Your Glory" (Khevodekha, כְּבֹדֶֽךָ) in Shemot (Exodus) 33:18 simply refer to the Smoke - hovering over Mount Horeb and the Ark?

Tags: exodus

Does "Your Glory" (Khevodekha, כְּבֹדֶֽךָ) in Shemot (Exodus) 33:18 simply refer to the Smoke - hovering over Mount Horeb and the Ark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

כָּבוֹד usually refers to someone's honor or reputation, as BDB says, "honour, splendour, glory, of external condition and circumstances".

This is confirmed by what occurs in Ex 33:18, 19 -

> Then Moses said, “Please show me Your glory.”
>
> “I will cause all My goodness to pass before you,” the LORD replied,
> “and I will proclaim My name—the LORD—in your presence. I will have
> mercy on whom I have mercy, and I will have compassion on whom I have
> compassion.”

Then in Ex 34:5-7 we have  -

> And the LORD descended in a cloud, stood with him there, and
> proclaimed His name, the LORD. Then the LORD passed in front of Moses
> and called out:
>
> “The LORD, the LORD God, is compassionate and gracious, slow to anger,
> abounding in loving devotion and faithfulness, maintaining loving
> devotion to a thousand generations, forgiving iniquity, transgression,
> and sin.
>
> Yet He will by no means leave the guilty unpunished; He will visit the
> iniquity of the fathers on their children and grandchildren to the
> third and fourth generations.”

Note that while the glory of the LORD is his reputation of compassion, patience, loving devotion, etc, the cloud/smoke is a symbol of that glorious reputation which was to accompany the Israelites in their desert wanderings.